# Unable to display French characters in RSS feed without encoding errors

Tags: xml, character-encoding, rss

I am trying to display the contents of an RSS feed with sample data as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<rss version="2.0"> 
<channel> 
  <title>NHL.com Nouvelles</title> 
  <link>http://www.nhl.com</link> 
  <description>Nouvelles</description> 
  <copyright>NHL Enterprises, L.P. (c) 2011 NHL. All Rights Reserved</copyright> 
  <language>fr-ca</language> 
  <lastBuildDate>Sun, 31 Jul 2011 21:14:47 EDT</lastBuildDate> 

  <item> 
    <title>L'attaquant Zach Parise signe un contrat d'une 
           saison avec les Devils
     </title> 
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.nhl.com/ice/news.htm?id=585498&cmpid=rss-Nouvelles]]>
     </link>    
    <description><![CDATA[ NEWARK, Ã‰tats-Unis - 
      L'attaquant Zach Parise a acceptÃ© un contrat d'une saison avec 
      les Devils du New Jersey.  Lors de l'annonce en fin d'aprÃ¨s-midi vendredi, 
      le prÃ©sident et directeur-gÃ©nÃ©ral des Devils Lou Lamoriello 
      a ajoutÃ© que les deux parti...]]>
     </description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 29 Jul 2011 19:04:04 EDT</pubDate> 
    <guid><![CDATA[http://www.nhl.com/ice/news.htm?id=585498]]></guid>
  </item>       

  <!-- other item nodes -->

  </channel> 
</rss>
```

The feed is encoded as **ISO-8859-1**. I have tried two scripts to display the feed on my site and it doesn't appear correct. I noticed that even when viewing the XML file in my browser the characters are not displayed properly.

I have used two different JavaScript solutions to display the feed on my site and neither of them display the characters properly either.

Does anyone know a pre-built RSS to HTML script in any language that will encode the incoming XML file properly?

If not, any suggestions on how I can encode it properly myself?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem before.

You will need to change the `charset` in your HTML.

This worked for me.

`<meta charset="ISO-8859">`

**EDIT**

Just noticed this too... your `description` content is garbled.  You will need to re-enter it in your text-editor or whatever you are using to code.  Looks like that program/application mangled it.  Could be part of the reason nothing is working.

```
<description><![CDATA[ NEWARK, Ã‰tats-Unis - 
  L'attaquant Zach Parise a acceptÃ© un contrat d'une saison avec 
  les Devils du New Jersey.  Lors de l'annonce en fin d'aprÃ¨s-midi vendredi, 
  le prÃ©sident et directeur-gÃ©nÃ©ral des Devils Lou Lamoriello 
  a ajoutÃ© que les deux parti...]]>
 </description>
```

Also, you should consider changing the French characters to ascii or hex values, like

`téléphonique`

to

`t&#233;l&#233;phonique`